# How to use result of one threaded function in another deferred thread twisted

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, twisted.web

My Twisted server code:

```
@app.route("/output", methods=['GET'])
@inlineCallbacks
@authenticate
def predict(request):
    request_params = request.args
    logger.debug("request param are {}".format(request_params))
    output = request_params['text']
    RESPONSE = yield threads.deferToThread(inference,output)
    PTAG = yield threads.deferToThread(tagging,RESPONSE['modified'],pattern1,pattern2)
    RESULT = yield threads.deferToThread(result,RESPONSE['modified'],enco)
```

Now for method tagging, I want to make use of key 'modified' of RESPONSE dictionary from first yield.
But it seems to take more time than my synchronous server